# Javafx: setting a Tab mnemonics

Tags: tabs, javafx

Quick question: Is it possible to set a mnemonic for a JavaFX Tab?

I can only seem to be able to set them for such controls as buttons, and menu items.

Comment: I just filed an enhancement request with Oracle for Tabs to have Mnemonics: [JDK-8192787](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8192787).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, this is an interesting question! You are right, you can not set the mnemonic directly on a Tab. But you can add a component as a Tabs graphic that supports the mnemonic feature:

```
private class MTab extends Tab
{
    public MTab(String pText)
    {
        super();
        Button fakeLabel = new Button(pText);
        fakeLabel.setMnemonicParsing(true);
        fakeLabel.getStyleClass().clear();
        setGraphic(fakeLabel);
        fakeLabel.setOnAction(ev -> {
            if (getTabPane() != null) {
                getTabPane().getSelectionModel().select(this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Using this tab:

```
TabPane tabs = new TabPane();
tabs.getTabs().add(new MTab("_this is a test"));
tabs.getTabs().add(new MTab("t_his is a test"));
tabs.getTabs().add(new MTab("th_is is a test"));
```

Will make your tabs switchable via shortcuts.

Comment: As an alternative solution, I thought maybe you could just `.lookup()` the tab's `.label`s, but that *does not* work!